# JavaScript running without waiting for AJAX request to finish

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a small problem, I want to check if a user is logged in via AJAX POST to a PHP and then run the rest of the function, unfortunately the rest of the function is being ran without waiting for the AJAX to finish.. so that's bad news

```
function checkLogin() {
    dat = 'chl=1&x='+Math.random();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/action.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: dat,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data)
                return data;
            return 0;
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log('err'+data);
            return;
        }
    });     
}
function anotherFunction() {
      logged = checkLogin(); // is the user logged in?
      if (logged) {
         // do other stuff
         console.log('Logged in');
      } else {
         console.log('Not logged in..');
      }
}
```

So this is my problem, it says logged is undefined.. Is there any solution to this, besides using setTimeout, something more "natural" in terms of time of wait?

Comment: I suggest putting the `if (logged)` logic into the AJAX "success" callback.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is asynchronous--do it in the `success:` code.

Answer (score -2):

Make it a synchronous request by adding asynch parameter and set it to false [not recommneded]

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/action.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: dat,
    asynch: false,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data)
            return data;
        return 0;
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log('err'+data);
        return;
    }
```

[Recommended] call your desired method in success call back of Ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "/action.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: dat,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data)
            return data;
        yourDesiredFunctionHere();
        return 0;     

    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log('err'+data);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: asynch? this is not the param you are looking for. Also setting it to that is a bad idea, re-factor the code.

Comment: asynch is still not the property name ;) also your `yourDesiredFunctionHere` function is after the return statement so wouldn't hit.